# Dual boot two Linux Distros and share /home partition?

Tags: partition, dual-boot

I already have Windows 10 and Manjaro installed on my system. Recently, something messed up my Manjaro install, and I wanted to also have a more stable OS on there like Elementary OS. Is there any way that I can have Manjaro and Elementary share the Swap, EFI, and Home partitions without deleting or ruining any of my current files? If so, how would I do it? Just turn off formatting of the mentioned partitions and add a Root one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just turn off formatting of the mentioned partitions and add a Root one?

That's pretty much it, yeah. Though there are some caveats:

- Be sure neither distro leaves the swap partition in a mess for the other to find. Not sure of defaults, but the swap partition can be configured as the storage location for hibernation data. Though worst case is probably just that the swap partition would fail to mount.
- Sharing `/home` could get messy if you use different versions of the same software under the different distros. Some things could also get confusing if the system-level defaults differ and either are or aren't overridden by the local configs in `$HOME`. *Personally*, assuming I had the disk space, I'd create a new home partition, mount the old one somewhere like `/old_home` or `/other_home`, and copy/symlink as appropriate, at least for a while. You can always switch around mountpoints later (editing `fstab` isn't hard).

And of course, `insert obligatory reminder to keep backups here`.

Comment: Your /home configuration files are tiny. Its your data that is large and what you want to share. So make a shared data partition and keep /home inside / of each install. My Ubuntu install is 8 to 9GB with /home but some hidden folders like Firefox & Thunderbird also moved to data partition for easier sharing. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk